# What is the meaning of text on Jesse's shoes in S03E12 in Breaking Bad?

Tags: analysis, breaking-bad

In S03E12, when Jesse is walking to kill two of Gus's enforcers, the camera shows the back of Jesse's shoes and there is a text there. [Right this scene](https://youtu.be/XN8qi6xWFb4?t=429). I think it says "PAID". I think this is yet another symbolism. Could you explain the meaning of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are "Osiris 'Get Paid' Bronx Lifestyle Shoes." Osiris appears to be a brand targeted to "skater/surf culture." Certainly they are in character for Jesse, but it is debatable whether this carries any further meaning within the story.

I suspect that these were a Wardrobe Department choice rather than an editorial one.

[image: Google Search]

Answer (score 0):

This might well be implying the payback. In many cases Breaking Bad producers show things that have not yet happened. That being said, the next thing is the two enforcers get ran over by Walter.